# convert doctrine resultset to json from findby query using zend json

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've seend much assistance for everything **BUT** transforming data when using the findBy query.

What I want is a json string of the resulset from this query ensuring that the objects are serialized so i can use this somewhere else:

```
$posts = $entityManager->getRepository(\Application\Entity\Post::class)
        ->findBy(['status'=>\Application\Entity\Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED],
            ['dateCreated'=>'DESC']);
```

`Json::encode($posts,true)` from `Zend Framework Json` but the data is not showing up when i do this.

**The result will be a json encoded string with the entity objects that i can pass somewhere else**

I will use for the decoding:

`\Zend\Json\Decoder::decode($posts,\Zend\Json\Json::TYPE_OBJECT)`

UNLESS I should be using `\Zend\Json\Json::TYPE_ARRAY)`

Comment: The problem there is $post is an ArrayCollection/PersistCollection. And any post's relation can be a doctrine proxy to load data lazily. It should be better if you transform $posts in array then you **encode** (not decode) to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I do it :

include : `use Zend\Json\Json;`

here is my example of function / action :

```
public function getListAction(){
        $request   = $this->getRequest();
        if($request->isPost()){
            // recuperer le produit choisi :
            $element = $request->getPost("element");
            $result = null;
            $result = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Element')->findBy(array('etat' => 'valide' , 'pkElement' => $element));
            $champs = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($result as $value) {
                $champs[$i] = array("id"=>$value->getPkElement() , "nom"=>$value->getNom());
                $i++;
            }
            $data = array(
                'result' => true,
                'data' => $champs
            );
            return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($data));
        }
    }
```

Then the call in the view.phtml :

```
$.post('/application/controller_name/getList', {element: $("select[name=element]").val()}, function(result) {
            var options = $("select[name=element]");
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);
            var data = obj.data;
            var selected = "";
            options.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               options.append($("<option />").val(data[i]['id']).text(data[i]['nom']));
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.